# password_verify returning false

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run) < 1)
    {
        header("Location: ../index.php?login=username");
        exit(); 
    }
    else
    {
        if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run))
        {
            //deshashing password
            $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($password, $row['password']);
            if($hashedPwdCheck == false)
            {
                header("Location: ../index.php?login=false");
                exit(); 
            }
            elseif($hashedPwdCheck == true)
            {
                //login the user here
                $_SESSION ['u_name'] = $row['username'];
                $_SESSION ['u_email'] = $row['email'];
                $_SESSION ['u_password'] = $row['password'];
                $_SESSION ['u_id'] = $row['userid'];

                header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
                exit();
```

above is the login code.

Below is the register code that stores the password and hashes it.

```
                    else
                    {
                        //hashing password
                        $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                        //insert the user into the database
                        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$hashedPwd');";
                        mysqli_query($con, $query);

                        header("Location: ../register.php?register=success");
                        exit();
                    }
```

Please help, I'm a little confused as to why this isn't working.

Regards,
Ross

Comment: what this function do password_verify paste content of this function... another observation this has sql injection

Comment: Is the columns width where you're storing the passwords more than 60 characters long?

Comment: Where does the $password variable come from.also show your database schema

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: ***Do not store the password in a session variable!***

Comment: What possible reason do you have to store the users password anywhere except the hashed version in the database?

Comment: It should just be `if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {`

Comment: He can store it in a variable if he wants @GrumpyCrouton, it just isn't necessary.

Comment: Show us the table details where the password is stored.

Comment: There is no sql_injection as I have a function on my variables that turns the text inputted in to plain text. mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['registerEmail']);

The fix was that the column I was storing the password in was only 50 character long. I upped that to 150 and it's working. Thank you all for your help :)

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ @GrumpyCrouton

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The column in which you're storing the hashed password is not long enough. It should be more than 60 characters and I suggest either `VARCH(255)` or `TEXT` to account for any future changes to the `password_hash()` function which may create longer hashes.

### WARNING

You should not store the password in the session array as it exposes the potential for getting the password hijacked.

[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

> "There is no sql_injection as I have a function on my variables that turns the text inputted in to plain text. `mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['registerEmail']);` "

***Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!***